# HttpServlet using @Path("/path") with @POST versus doPost

Tags: java, servlets

I am a little confused on HttpServlet usage of @Path("/path") with an @POST method versus doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) method.  I have seen many good working examples of the @Path usage but never a working example of the doPost.  When ever I attempt to use the doPost it never gets called.

First, what's the difference, and which is a better way to go?  Also, what am I doing wrong with the doPost

```
public class PostExample extends HttpServlet{


@Override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

    // HttpServlet doPost never gets called
    System.out.println("hit test doPost "+request.getRequestURI());


}
 }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"what's the difference, and which is a better way to go"
```

The annotation @GET, @PUT, @POST, @DELETE and @HEAD are part of JAX-RS: Java API for RESTful Web Services specification to specify the HTTP request type of a resource and are implemented in Web Service frameworks like Jersey and Apache CXF and you won't be using them until you actually use those frameworks.

[Wiki JAX-RS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_RESTful_Web_Services)

```
"what am I doing wrong with the doPost"
```

You need to specify the servlet in your web.xml

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>PostExample</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.examples.PostExample</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>PostExample</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/myservlet/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: First of all thank you for the explanation!

I am using Jersey, and have the servlet registered in the web.xml file under both implementaions - I just comment the necessary blocks when testing in the classes.  

Having said that, why doesn't the doPost get called?  the @POST designated method gets called just fine?

Comment: For clarification, does the doPost method need to get manually called from @POST designated method?  I understand the 'service' method is suppose to call 'doPost' automatically.

Comment: @POST annotation designates that the method responds to HTTP POST requests, it does not matter what your method name is inside it..it can be public void doPost() or public String doPost() or public String postMe(). You get to play things the same you do in a normal doPost method of HttpServlet. Here is an example as you asked [example](https://github.com/gmazza/jersey-samples-on-cxf/blob/master/simple-servlet/src/main/java/com/sun/jersey/samples/servlet/resources/ResourceBean3.java)

Comment: Okay so I think I am starting to understand:  The doPost method I originally posted in the question is a non-RESTful implementation outside of Jersey - notice the parameters in the method.  There are no @... annotations in the example I posted.  This taken verbatim from another supposedly working example.

Comment: Post any comments if you still have any doubts?

Comment: Conclusion:  The non-RESTful implementation framework is not included in my implementation (using Jersey) so therefore the RESTful methodology works but the non-RESTful methodology method 'doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)' has no framework installed to support it and thus is never called when the servlet runs a POST request.